# Пропуск инициализации wstring из-за goto

Tags: c++

```
if(blablabla) goto mmClean;
const size_t cSize2 = strlen(...);
std::wstring wc2(cSize2, L'#');
mmClean:
...
```

компилятор выкидывает ошибку что не может инициализировать wc2 из-за метки mmClean.
Да, знаю что goto использовать не стоит, но в моем случае он используется крайне редко когда для "правильного кода" нужно переписывать достаточно много.
В любом случае, как можно обозначить wc2 чтобы не выдавало ошибку? Может определить динамически? cSize2 может быть каким угодно в процессе

Comment: Может быть определить wstring ранее а потом как-нибудь переписать его размер? (не через цикл. если можно, какие-нибудь варианты использования готовых функций)

Comment: Тут проблема даже не столько в самом `goto`, сколько в метке `mmClean`. Такое название метки явно говорит о том, что вы занимаетесь ручной подчисткой вместо RAII.

Comment: Прыжок через инициализацию `cSize2` приведет к той же ошибке, так что дело тут не только в `wc2`.

Comment: @AnT на удивление, на cSize2 не ругается. Видимо из-за const

Comment: @user2173645: Странно. У меня ругается http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f671d9e3e3afadfe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (blablabla) goto mmClean;

{
    const size_t cSize2 = strlen(...);
    std::wstring wc2(cSize2, L'#');
}
mmClean:
```

Все объявления переменных следует ограничить операторными скобками, ограничивая тем самым их время жизни. Причину попытаюсь объяснить на примере:
выполняется программа
допустим, что выражение blablabla истинно, тогда goto пропустит объявление и инициализация cSize2 и wc2.
Но никто вам не мешает после mmClean использовать эти переменные, никто кроме компилятора, который любезно останавливает вас от неправильных действий.
Решение - ограничить жизнь переменных cSize2 и wc2: этим вы сообщите компилятору, что после метки goto вы не собираетесь использовать эти переменные (а если собираетесь - значит у вас неправильный дизайн функции)