# Объявление string в switch приводит к ошибке "cannot jump from switch statement to this case label"

Tags: c++, switch, инициализация

Обнаружил для себя такую неожиданную вещь: код

```
switch (a) {
    case 1:
        std::string alfa;
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

не компилируется из-за объявления переменной класса `string`. Компилятор выдает, что не может прыгнуть к следующей метке:

```
1.cpp:16:9: error: cannot jump from switch statement to this case label
    default:
    ^
```

Но почему так? Почему, если объявить, например, переменную типа `int`, то все в порядке?

Comment: То же самое, что и здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/853515/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-wstring-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0-goto#comment1375729_853515. Если объявить переменную типа `int` с *инициализатором*, то будет та же ошибка.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Смотрите - а что ему делать, если вы получите `a==2` и при этом решите в ветви обратиться к этой переменной `alfa`? Инициализировать ее? нет?

Во избежание таких фокусов - перепрыгивания через инициализацию - это считается ошибкой.

Просто возьмите переменную в фигурные скобки, чтоб ограничить область видимости:

```
switch (a) {
    case 1:
        {
            std::string alfa;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 17):

Вариант с `int var;` работает потому, что такая запись не приводит к какой-либо инициализации. Стоит добавить инициализацию, как также получим ошибку "перепрыгивания". `std::string` же сложный класс со своим конструктором, поэтому явная инициализация не требуется и всё равно будет вызван конструктор по умолчанию.

При этом для `int` остаётся возможность присвоить переменной значение и работать с ней как ни в чём ни бывало в любой ветке ниже определения переменной.

Comment: Уточню, что `int var;` — это statement с *default initialization* — инициализацией, которая не содержит *initializer*. Именно добавление *initializer* приводит к нарушению правила ["scalar types declared without initializers"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/goto), которое позволяет `int var;` компилироваться. Другими словами, есть "инициализация" как процесс присвоения начального значения (её нет для `int`, о чём и идёт речь в ответе), а есть синтаксическая конструкция "инициализация по-умолчанию" (она есть и для `int`, и для `std::string`, но эффект разный).