# Ошибка инициализации из-за метки case

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Никак не могу понять, в чём ошибка в коде. Например, если я пишу вот так:

```
fstream f("data.txt");
switch (choosing)
{
case 1:
        f >> size >> x;

        break;
case 2:

    break;
}
```

То всё работает пркрасно, но, если я напишу:

```
switch (choosing)
{
case 1:
        fstream f("data.txt");
        f >> size >> x;

        break;
case 2:

    break;
}
```

То получуошибку вида:

```
Ошибка  C2360   пропуск инициализации "f" из-за метки "case"    Train   d:\c++ projects\train\train\source.cpp  71
```

Вопрос, что не так? Ведь по сути, я просто переношу инициализацую файловой переменной изнутри case наружу?

Comment: дубликат вопроса https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/857066/Странности-со-switch/857072#857072

Comment: "...просто переношу инициализацую файловой переменной изнутри case наружу"? Ничего себе "просто"! Это же гигантское изменение. Во втором случае `case 2:` видит неинициализированную переменную. Об этом вам и говорит компилятор.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Дело в том что в С++ конструкция `switch` / `case` является замаскированным `goto` и `case` блоки не создают области видимости. У вас происходит примерно вот это:

```
if(1 == choosing)
{
    goto mark1;
}
if(2 == choosing)
{
    goto mark2;
}
{
    mark1:
    fstream f("data.txt");
    f >> size >> x;
    goto ending;
    mark2:
    // если choosing 2, то мы попадаем сюда, пропуская инициализацию f
    goto ending;
}
ending:;
```

Соответственно для каждого `case` следует вручную создавать новую область видимости:

```
switch (choosing)
{
    case 1:
    {
        fstream f("data.txt");
        f >> size >> x;
    }
    break;
    case 2:
    {
    }
    break;
}
```