# Почему мы можем пропустить определение переменной, перейдя сразу к присвоению этой переменной?

Tags: c++

```
switch (2) 
{
   case 1:
      int x;
   case 2:
      x = 23;
}

std::cout << x;
```

Давно уже не могу понять почему мы можем пропустить определение переменной, перейдя сразу к присвоению этой переменной? Почему (в этом контексте) пишут что это объявление, если это определение(ну и объявление, а вот наоборот - нет)?
Если это действительно было объявление, то тогда вышеизложенный код мне понятен.

Почему я не могу вывести значение `x`, ведь они находятся в одной области видимости.

Comment: фигурный скобки `{` , `}` и задают область видимости. По-этому вы переменную `x` и не можете вывести.

Answer (score 5):

Потому что как таковой инициализации `int` нет. Если вы вместо него используете какой-то объект посерьезнее, например, `string` —

```
switch (2)
{
case 1:
    int x;
    string a;
case 2:
    a = "2";
    x = 23;
}
```

то получите ошибку "пропуск инициализации `a` из-за метки `case`"... Кстати, стоит добавить  инициализацию этого `x`, как компилятор вас остановит:

```
switch (2)
{
case 1:
    int x = 5;
case 2:
    x = 23;
}
```

Все, этот код неверен из-за пропущенной инициализации.

Областью видимости `x` являются строки от его объявления до закрывающей фигурной скобки, поэтому вывести ее значение *вне* конструкции `switch` вы не можете.

Comment: [Хорошо забытое старое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/857072/176217)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Еще бы, 4.5 года назад... Кстати, хороший вопрос для меты - в какой мере задающий вопрос отвечает за поиск по сайту дубликата? :)

Comment: В какой-то отвечает. Некоторые вообще минусы лепят сразу, если дубликат быстро находится на сайте. Но всё это субъективно. На Мете обсудить, конечно, можно.

Answer (score 4):

Нужно отделять время компиляции и время выполнения программы.
На этапе компиляции будет определена переменная `int x;` с областью видимости и временем жизни внутри оператора `switch()`.
Т.е. вы не пропускаете объявление переменной, поместив его в `case 1:`.
Возможно для понимания так будет проще:

```
switch (2)
{
    int x;

    case 1:
    case 2:
        x = 23;
}
```

А вот в выражении `std::cout << x;` переменная `x` неизвестна, т.к. у ранее объявленной область видимости - блок оператора `switch()`.